# Nokogiri showing two times the same text despite existing only once in document. Bug?

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri

I am making a small scraper for the yahoo.finance.com website. When I make this request:

```
symbol = 'AAPL'

@page = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=#{symbol.upcase}&ql=1"))

def marketCap(symbol)
  @page.xpath("//*[(@id = \"yfs_j10_#{symbol.downcase}\")]").text
end

puts marketCap(symbol)
```

It prints two times the same result.

"495.74B495.74B"

I looked at the source code and the tag is only showing it once

```
<span id="yfs_j10_f">51.74B</span>
```

If I use a css selector instead I get the same problem.

Is it a bug or did I made a mistake?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@page.xpath("//*[(@id = \"yfs_j10_#{symbol.downcase}\")]").text
```

isn't correct.

`xpath` returns a NodeSet, which is similar to an Array. If it contains two elements `text` will contain both of them:

```
@page.xpath("//*[(@id = \"yfs_j10_#{symbol.downcase}\")]").size
=>2
```

Instead, use `at_xpath` to find the first one.

```
@page.at_xpath("//*[(@id = \"yfs_j10_#{symbol.downcase}\")]").text
=> "495.74B"
```

Now, instead of using XPath, which I feel is usually more complicated and less readable, I'd recommend using CSS for your accessor:

```
@page.at("#yfs_j10_#{symbol.downcase}").text
=> "495.74B"
```

Notice that I used `at` instead of `at_css` or `at_xpath`. `at` senses whether you're passing an XPath or CSS. It's generic, and could make a mistake figuring out which to use, but it's also easier to use. The same is true of `search` instead of `css` or `xpath`. It returns a NodeSet like the other two, but senses which type of accessor it should use.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation. I already changed my code accordingly to your suggestions and it works perfectly. It looks much better too :)

Comment: Parsing documents is an interesting learning experience, but, once you learn, it's just one more data-type available to you. Nokogiri is a great parser, and its implementation of CSS goes a long way toward simplifying the task.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem. It looks like it was conflicting with another selector.

This solved the problem

```
def marketCap(symbol)
  @page.css("#yfi_comparison #yfs_j10_#{symbol.downcase}").text
end
```

Comment: You should take the Tin Man's suggestion and use `at` instead of `css`